# How does one simply, print words on paper with VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, printing

So I have an array of strings that I want to print, one string on one line. Simple. But it appears I have to write a whole [flipping printer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Is there a way to just print words, not draw and position all kinds of things but, something like `Printer.printline("print this stuff");`.

Comment: If you care this little what it looks like then simply write to a file instead with StreamWriter.WriteLine().  And ask Notepad to print it for you, Process class with the "Print" verb.  Easy peasy.

Comment: I would have, had that been an option for the assignment. The professor eventually removed the requirement because he did not get into that chapter, so this was all that necessary. Still though, I don't understand the down-votes, this seems like a a reasonable question: "how to print something?"

Answer (score 2):

With serial line printers that is exactly possible (`Serial.WriteLine(string)`), but most printers require use of an intermediate PDL.  Windows abstracts the specific PDL away through either the GDI Print Subsystem (`System.Drawing`) or the XPS Print Subsystem (`System.Printing` and `System.Windows`).

There is rarely a case where such a simple print API would be useful, since the first question asked after you hand a customer a print job is inevitably "can you make this bold?"  As such, you are expected to write your own wrapper if you want such a thing.